# Is there a way to set spacy's POS tagging?

Tags: python, spacy

We have a pandas dataframe with three columns: subject, verb, and object.

- In the subject column, the data looks like "I" or "we".
- In the verb column, it looks like "had" or "did not" or "loved".
- In the object column, it looks like "vacuum" or "floors."

I'm trying to lemmatize all of these columns with spacy to add three new columns: subject_lemma, verb_lemma, and object_lemma. I can do that with the code below, but I'm having the problem that some things aren't being properly lemmatized (e.g. a cell with "loved" in the verb column isn't being changed to the present tense "love", it's just staying the same). After doing some tests, I think that's because "loved" is being tagged by spacy as an adjective instead of a verb. Is there some way for me to address this? I was thinking that I could maybe set the pos tag for the whole verb column to verb so that it will correctly lemmatize verbs like "loved", but there are some words in the verb column that aren't verbs (e.g. not in "did not").

It could be there's another post on here that explains this, and sorry if I couldn't see it! Thanks very much for your advice!

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')

def spacy_lemmatizer(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    lemmatized_sentence = " ".join([token.lemma_ for token in doc])
    return(lemmatized_sentence)

dataframe.loc[:,'subject_lemma'] = dataframe.loc[:,'subject'].apply(spacy_lemmatizer)
dataframe.loc[:,'verb_lemma'] = dataframe.loc[:,'verb'].apply(spacy_lemmatizer)
dataframe.loc[:,'object_lemma'] = dataframe.loc[:,'object'].apply(spacy_lemmatizer)
```

Comment: If the tagging is such a POS, why would you want to set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that lemmatization does not *always* come out right. What's more problematic in your case, though, is that it is a context-sensitive operation. In the context of a sentence, "loved" is correctly recognized as a verb and lemmatized accordingly. My solution would be to pass *complete* sentences to SpaCy and re-map the resulting lemmas to the original tokenization afterwards, which is somewhat more work, but should get the best results in terms of lemmatization.

##### 1. Re-joining and `nlp`-ing the sentences

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([['He', 'loved', 'floors'],
                                ['I', 'don\'t like', 'vacuums']], columns=['subject', 'verb', 'object'])

df['raw_tokens'] = df[['subject', 'verb', 'object']].values.tolist()
df['doc'] = df.raw_tokens.agg(' '.join).apply(nlp)
```

```py
  subject        verb   object                raw_tokens                          doc
0      He       loved   floors       [He, loved, floors]          (He, loved, floors)
1       I  don't like  vacuums  [I, don't like, vacuums]  (I, do, n't, like, vacuums)
```

##### 2. Aligning the two tokenizations

We need to turn the `doc` column into a list of lemmas which we can regroup later on while **preserving the original tokenization**. One way to achieve this is to use SpaCy's builtin [`Alignment`](https://spacy.io/api/example#alignment-object) module. Given two lists of tokens with different tokenizations, this will give you a mapping of one list to the other by indices, e.g.,

```py
from spacy.training import Alignment

raw_toks = ['I', "don't like", 'vacuums']
spacy_toks = ['I', 'do', "n't", 'like', 'vacuums']

alignment = Alignment.from_strings(raw_toks, spacy_toks)

# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(list(alignment.x2y.dataXd))

# [0, 1, 1, 1, 2]
print(list(alignment.y2x.dataXd))
```

This tells us that the tokens at index 1, 2, and 3 in `spacy_toks` belong to token 1 in `raw_toks`. In the function below, I used that to map tokens to the original tokenization after processing them with SpaCy, but instead of token strings, we collect lemmas. The idea is to turn an input like `spacy_toks` above into `[['I'], ['do', "n't", 'like'], ['vacuum']]`.

```py
from spacy.training import Alignment
from itertools import groupby

def lemmatize(row):
    
    tokens, lemmas = zip(*((x.text, x.lemma_) for x in row.doc))
    lemmas = iter(lemmas) # so we can use next()
    
    # get alignment of surface token strings 
    alignment = Alignment.from_strings(row.raw_tokens, tokens).y2x.dataXd
    lemma_map = list()
    
    # collect lemmas into subgroups
    for _,g in groupby(alignment):
        lemma_map.append([next(lemmas) for _ in g])
    
    return [' '.join(w) for w in lemma_map]
```

##### 3. Applying it to the dataframe

```py
df['lemmas'] = df.apply(lemmatize, axis=1)

# some cleaning
df[['subject_lemma', 'verb_lemma', 'object_lemma']] = pd.DataFrame(df.lemmas.tolist(), index=df.index)
```

**Final result:**

```py
  subject        verb   object subject_lemma   verb_lemma object_lemma
0      He       loved   floors            he         love        floor
1       I  don't like  vacuums             I  do n't like       vacuum
```

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness and future reference, I just came across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67789544/given-a-word-can-we-get-all-possible-lemmas-for-it-using-spacy) which points to the module [LemmInflect](https://github.com/bjascob/LemmInflect) that looks like another really good alternative.