# Get all possible lemmas for a single word in Spanish (and other non-English languages)

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, lemmatization

Given a single word I would like to get all the possible lemmas of that word. I am using Spacy 3. The following code will output up to one lemma for a given word. It doesn't find alternatives.

```
import spacy

# Load Spanish model
nlp = spacy.load("es_core_news_sm", disable=['parser', 'ner'])

text = "habla"
doc = nlp(text)

for token in doc:
    print("{:<12}{:<12}{:<12}{:<12}".format(token.text, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.lemma_))

# Outputs:
# text = "habla" (you/he/she speaks; speech)
# habla       VERB        VERB        hablar
# "hablar" = to speak (verb). However "habla" also means "speech" (noun)

# text = "como" (I eat; as)
# como        SCONJ       SCONJ       como
# not returning possible verb lemma - "comer" - to eat

# text = "come" (you/he/she eats)
# come        VERB        VERB        come
# lemma should be "comer" not "come"

# text = "sabe" (you/she/he knows)
# sabe        VERB        VERB        saber
# Correct lemmatization of "sabe"
```

In all cases, only one of the possible lemmas is being returned even where there are more possibilities.

Solutions that I have tried:

- [lemminflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67789544/given-a-word-can-we-get-all-possible-lemmas-for-it-using-spacy) - possibly only works for English
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64731868/spacy-how-to-manually-set-pos-tag-for-vertical-bar), in which you'd set a part of speech tag (and could therefore loop through all possible tags), but that seems to be for an older version of spacy

The best alternative solution I have found is to use the [Oxford Dictionaries API](https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/documentation#!/Sentences/get_sentences_source_lang_word_id) - that only supports a few languages - it doesn't provide lemmas for French for example.

Comment: spaCy just isn't designed to do this. See this question: [Given a word can we get all possible lemmas for it using Spacy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67789544/given-a-word-can-we-get-all-possible-lemmas-for-it-using-spacy)